# onClick eventlistener in JS without using onclick function in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html file and js file I want to execute JS when a button is clicked in html. for this I can use onclick event in html but the condition is that I should not modify the HTML file.

I tried to add eventlistener in my JS but that didn't worked.

```
<p align=center>
    <button class="stdbutton" id=button2 name=button2>
        Click Me
    </button>
</p>
```

```js
$("button2").click(function() {
    alert("button2 clicked");
});
```

please see the fiddle link for further reference: http://jsfiddle.net/gqpr0g9w/

thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is marked with jQuery, yet your fiddle is using Mootools... I'm confused. If you change the fiddle to jQuery and fix the selector to add the `#` then it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/gqpr0g9w/2/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan : i think you got it right ,.. why dont you make your comment as an answer ..

Comment: It's not really an answer that will help anyone in future so if that did solve it, it would probably be best for the OP to just delete this question.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/30w751ew/3/),

Basically the first issue with your fiddle was you are using js library other than jquery. Jquery code won't execute without referencing the jquery library.

Secondly you are using an invalid selector,

```
$("button2")
```

you can replace this with an id based selector (**#** selector) as per your markup

```
$("#button2")
```

And finally try wrapping the code under jquery closure under `document ready event` that will ensure that the event will attach when the related object is loaded on the browser.

Finally will becomes

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button2").click(function() {
    alert("button2 clicked");
  });
});
```

Hope it works for you..

Answer (score 0):

Include jQuery in your jsfiddle. Use one of the below to attach an event listener for click using jQuery

```
$("#button2").on("click", function() {
   alert("button 2 clicked");
});
```

or

```
$("#button2").click(function() {
   alert("button2 clicked");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

case jQuery is included in the html:
js file -

```
$("#button2").click(function() {
    alert("button2 clicked");
});
```

// notice the # symbol before the word "button2" representing that we are looking for an ID

case jQuery is NOT included in the html:

> ```
> <script src="lib/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
> <script src="js/myJavaScript.js"></script>
> ```
>
> jQuery script must first be included
>   and then you can execute the same code as shown above.

Answer (score -1):

Well, you are trying to use jQuery, but there is no jQuery included in your html-File. In fact there is no script included in your html at all like

```
<script src="lib/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/myJavaScript.js"></script>
```

I don't think you will be able to do that without modifying the html-file.